# Visual Studio Code - Where is the terminal history saved?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed that the command history is saved when using *Visual Studio Code*.  Using the arrow up and down keys, I can toggle through previously issued commands in the integrated terminal.

Where is the terminal history saved on the drive? Is it possible to open a file in notepad (or notepad++) and investigate the complete history, delete it?

I'm using Windows 10, and I have concluded that deleting the folders `C:\Users\john\.vscode` and `C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\Code` will not delete the terminal history for a particular project.

Comment: Which shell you are using? `bash`, `powershell` or others?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

VSCode terminal use external shell. For linux the default shell is `bash`, I am not so sure about window, but I guess the default shell for window is `powershell`.

If your terminal shell is indeed `powershell`, [this](https://0xdf.gitlab.io/2018/11/08/powershell-history-file.html) should help you locate the log file.

Comment: That's correct, `powershell` and the history is indeed saved in `C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline`

Comment: thanks guys exact solution that I needed +1 for both

Answer (score 19):

On Linux & MacOS, type the following command to display the path of the history file:

```bash
echo $HISTFILE
```

The history file may be different between VSCode and your regular terminal.
So you should type this command within the integrated terminal.

Comment: to read: sudo cat /Users/user.../.zsh_history

Comment: `echo $HISTFILE` also works in Bash on Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu you can see your history using this command:

```sh
vi ~/.bash_history
```

Comment: If you've updated to zsh, it's found at
vi ~/.zsh_history